# Xcode 4.4.1 build crashing on Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode4

I have a project which I am compiling under OS X 10.7.4 using Xcode 4.4.1

I am using Base SDK SDKROOT macosx10.7
I have set Deployment Target MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET   10.6

I tested a recent build on Snow Leopard and it crashed.
Previous builds using Xcode 4.2 and 4.3 did work, and I can compile on Snow Leopard using Xcode version 3.2.6

Has anyone else had this experience, or better know what I can do to resolve it?

```
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000030
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc[274]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit                 -[NSImage _allocAuxiliaryStorage] + 158
1   com.apple.AppKit                 -[NSImage copyWithZone:] + 66
2   libobjc.A.dylib                  objc_setProperty + 82
3            -[TreeViewController(Dirs) outlineView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:item:] + 207
```

---

**PS Just restored Xcode 4.2.1 from TimeMachine backup and the build works on Snow Leopard**

I "upgraded" to Mountain Lion - which would not allow Xcode 4.2.1 to run.
(This also seemed to delete the OSX 10.8 and Xcode 4.4 SDK and the command line tools :-( ).
This made it impossible to just use the precious compiler.

I tried to follow up where the crash was happening, which appeared to be in a call to setNodeIcon which was defined in one of my classes as

```
@property (copy) NSImage *nodeIcon;
```

I realise I will have to convert to ARC eventually, but was reluctant to embark on this yet.
The conversion was far from straightforward and I am not sure I understand all the changes I was required to make (one file at a time) in particular the Toll-Free Bridging changes.

The resultant ARC code does seem to work on 10.6 - 10.8 but I need to do a lot of regression and leak testing to confirm.

---

### Updated Comments 2012-09-18

The  ARC code works but I found a couple of problems (which I have resolved) but need to do a lot more.

I went back to my GC code and changed `copy` to `assign`. This seemed to work.

```
@property (assign) NSImage *nodeIcon;
```

Just to confirm I made a standalone app (see below) which does nothing but copy an NSImage.
This crashed in the same way, so it seems to be a bug in the compiler.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSImage *nodeIcon;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (copy) NSImage *nodeIcon;

@end

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize nodeIcon;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSString *defaultDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();
    [self setNodeIcon:[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:defaultDirectory]];
}

@end
```

Comment: The garbage collection could be the problem. Apple is phasing out support for garbage collection. I noticed in Xcode 4.4 the build setting to enable garbage collection was removed.

Comment: I am not sure GC is the problem, but I started to investigate and apparently GC is deprecated in 10.8 http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/memory.html suggests including GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC, which is already there. This is a bit of a catch 22. So many people are still using Snow Leopard, which I am told does not fully support ARC.

Comment: The one ARC feature I'm aware of that Snow Leopard doesn't support is weak references to objects. If you need weak references in Snow Leopard, Mike Ash has a [PLWeakCompatibility](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/PLWeakCompatibility) project on github you should take a look at. Xcode has a refactoring tool you can access from the Edit menu that converts your project to ARC. It will take a snapshot before the conversion so you can go back if the conversion causes problems.