# cooca - Mac OS X 10.6.8 only crash

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, crash, osx-snow-leopard

I am having strange crash only on 10.6.8 and on all other system above it works fine. Below is the dump of crashed thread from crash log. Can you please help me on this. I am also not that much use to Instrument tool so was not able to go to map memory location to code in app.

```
Process:         ABCD [1235]
Path:            /Applications/ABCD.app/Contents/MacOS/ABCD
Identifier:      com.xyz.abcd
Version:         2.3 (666)
App Item ID:     411680127
App External ID: 335162646
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [90]

Architecture:   i386
Date/Time:       2014-02-09 22:28:50.554 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000030
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc[1235]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff89e7f9de -[NSImage _allocAuxiliaryStorage] + 158
1   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a003f05 -[NSImage copyWithZone:] + 66
2   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a2ee43c -[NSNavView _setupNormalFileListModeControl] + 154
3   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a2eef32 -[NSNavView awakeFromNib] + 204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff83b6d9fd -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 205
5   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff89e7a85b -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1445
6   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff89f21d14 -[NSNib instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:] + 564
7   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff89f21a92 -[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 233
8   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a2efb07 +[NSNavView navView] + 109
9   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a35d062 -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout) _initContentView] + 1230
10  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a35660b -[NSSavePanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 367
11  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a35aaf5 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 198
12  com.xyz.abcd                        0x000000010000a174 0x100000000 + 41332
13  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a00beda -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 95
14  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a00be39 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 94
15  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a09784b -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1715
16  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a0c837a -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 555
17  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff8a0962f5 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 624
18  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff89fb03a7 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 5409
19  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff89ee5afa -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4719
20  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff89e7c6de -[NSApplication run] + 474
21  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff89e753b0 NSApplicationMain + 364
22  com.xyz.abcd                        0x0000000100002334 0x100000000 + 9012
```

Comment: are you using ARC? And if yes, have you defined some variable as weak?

Comment: No, I am not using ARC as it's very old project and complex to convert. I suspect it is only crashing when NSOpenPanel is being used.

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209919/xcode-4-4-1-build-crashing-on-snow-leopard